# Missing utility.h from MXChip Sample files for DPS Demo

Tags: azure

All,
    I am trying to track down why I am missing this utility.h library from my code.  I have all paths configured in Arduino and VS Code...however, upon compiling I get the error:

> ```
> [Starting] Verify sketch - DevKitDPS\DevKitDPS.ino
> Loading configuration...
> Initializing packages...
> Preparing boards...
> Verifying...
> DevKitDPS:9:21: error: utility.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> exit status 1
> [Error] Exit with code=1
> ```

I am using the MXChip board and the code from the DPS Sample found here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-iot-workbench/blob/master/docs/iot-devkit/devkit_dps.md

I have installed all Azure libraries from the Arduino manage libraries...restarted, checked my paths to the libraries in VS Code...and all should be good... it just seems that I am missing the utility.h file all together...and I am not sure where this is coming from or where to pull it as part of a library package.

any thoughts on what I might be missing or where to check?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I ended up solving it by going to File > Save Workbench As... Once I did this, I was able to successfully compile the app.